# React Native call function outside of App. Flatlist access onPress function

Tags: react-native

There is example https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist
Let's say I want to add button in each flatlist item. All happens inside App.js

```
const Item = ({ item,.....}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={..}>
    <Button title='Go' onPress={() => myFunc('abc')} /> </TouchableOpacity>);

const App = () => {
 function myFunc(x){
 }
}
```

I get " ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myFunc "
I solved this by moving `Item` inside of `const App = () => {` but I think it might be wrong.

Tell me please, what is the correct way?

Comment: This happen because your myFunc method is inside App Component which is unknown for Item Component it is out of its scope so either you need to define your Item component inside App Component or you can pass myFunc method to Item Component as its props. Also I have written as sample as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    
const myFunc = (args) => {
  // perform your action here.
}
    
return (
  <FlatList
    data={[{ title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1' }]}
    renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={item.key}
          onPress={() => myFunc('abc')}
        >
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
   />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Also you do not need to using `TouchableOpacity` if you are using `Button` Component already.

And since you are using separate component to render item for `FlatList` so it can be done as below:

```
// Considering App as Parent Component
const App = () => {

// Considering Item as separate Component

const Item = ({item, index, separators}) => {
 return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={item.key}
      onPress={() => myFunc('abc')}
    >
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
        
const myFunc = (args) => {
 // perform your action here.
}
        
return (
  <FlatList
    data={[{ title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1' }]}
    renderItem={Item}
  />
 )
}
export default App;
```

All code are inside `App` Component;

Comment: Thx. What is the reason they put Item outside of App in documentation example?

Comment: As per documentation we can define our separate component in different way. As i have mention above separate component inside Parent component. But we can define separate component outside Parent component as well or in separate file. But the thing is in above question you haven't pass myFunc() method as props for separate component so that it can be used by separate component. In documentation you can see that at first Flatlist has call renderItem method where Item component is being call where the require props as being passed so that it can be used in Item component. :). Hope it is clear.